# How to Exclude list of string values from a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

```
 Dictionary<string, int?> tVers = null;
```

Below my list of string fetches data from one table entity

```
List<string> category = context.Cat
  .Where(c.Description != "abc")
  .Select(a => a.Name)
  .ToList();
```

Here i need to exclude the list of string values fetched in above list in my Tvers dictionary which fetches data from some other table entity,i.e.the TName of dictionary must exclude values from cat and return the dictiionary

```
tVers = context.MCurrentVer
  .Where(x => x.MKey == 1000)
  .ToDictionary(k => k.TName, 
                v => v.CVer);
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!category.Contains(x.TName)` to filter out `x.TName` that are in the `catrgory` list.

```
tVers = context.MCurrentVer
   .Where(x => x.MKey == 1000 && !category.Contains(x.TName))
   .ToDictionary(k => k.TName, v => v.CVer);
```

Comment: I think you can use .Any instead of .Contains if you think category and dictionary name would be in different case.

Comment: @ T.Rahgooy , also the condition c.Description !="abc" doesnt fetch the values where c.Description is NULL.is there any workaround for this?(i dont want to put (c.Description != "abc" && c.Description ==NULL)

Comment: no actually there is no error ,but my list is not fetching the records where C.Description value is NULL and i want NULL records also to be fetched .

Comment: Then you should use `(c.Description != "abc" || c.Description ==null)`, there is no workarounds I think.